# R, 2 dataframe, check if column exist and create new variable if not

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes want to have exact the same columns in order to perform merge(vertically) later. What I currently do is first manually check if df1 has each column in df2, if not, create a new column and assign null value like this `df1$v3 <- NA`.

However, df1 has much less columns than df2, which will make the code really long and not smart with my current way. I wonder if there is a efficient method to do it.

Here is an example:

```
v1<-c(1:5)
v2<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df1<-data.frame(v1,v2)
v3=c("de890","gyu","71g", "178sg", "ss10")
df2<-data.frame(v1,v2,v3)

df1
  v1 v2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
4  4  d
5  5  e

df2
  v1 v2    v3
1  1  a de890
2  2  b   gyu
3  3  c   71g
4  4  d 178sg
5  5  e  ss10
```

So since df1 dont have v3 column, I want to create a new one and name it as v3 and assign null, so the finally df1 would like this:

```
df1
  v1 v2    v3
1  1  a    NA
2  2  b    NA
3  3  c    NA
4  4  d    NA
5  5  e    NA
```

Would you please share some lights on how to do it efficiently?
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: If you want to merge the two dataframes, R will automatically assign `NA` values to the rows that lack the variables.

Comment: I try this code x<-rbind(df1,df2) and the error is Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match. So what I should do about this?

Comment: I guess `dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2)` is the function you want in the end.

Comment: in the end, i found out I still need to match two df have the same columns in order to use rbind. I am good now and thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to create unnecessary columns and assign them `NA`. However, You could do this:

```
v1<-c(1:5)
v2<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df1<-data.frame(v1,v2)
v3=c("de890","gyu","71g", "178sg", "ss10")\
v4<-c(1:5)
df2<-data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)

# Finding the columns not found in df1, but df2
cols<-setdiff(names(df2),names(df1))

# Looping to create them in df1
for(i in cols){df1[[i]]<-NA}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @LAP has mentioned that `merge` automatically adds columns with `NA` but if OP still wants to add column before hand then it can be achieved as:

```
df1[,setdiff(names(df2),names(df1))] <- NA
df1
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  a NA
# 2  2  b NA
# 3  3  c NA
# 4  4  d NA
# 5  5  e NA
```